# PHP SDK Opencloud/Openstack - How to add X-Storage-Policy in header?

Tags: openstack-swift, php-opencloud

I am using php sdk openstack v1 for opencloud and I would like to know while creating container I want to add custom header for "X-Storage-Policy" then how can i add custom header?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, its working by passing metadata argument while creating container.
Its done :) Thank you all